# Visual Studio 2015 - C# line break behavior after snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Since I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2015, an annoying, even frustrating, behavior has manifested. This occurs whenever I enter some kind of snippet (such as an `if` block by typing "if" followed by [Tab][Tab], or perhaps highlighting some code and using the "Surround With..." option). When I click after the closing bracket of said snippet and then hit [Enter], I would expect a line break to occur, resulting in something like this:

```
if (true)
{
    // some code
    // some more code
} // (right here, after the closing bracket, is where I clicked, then hit [Enter])
// new empty line
```

Instead, the line break does not occur, and the text focus is moved to inside the block after the last line of code, like so:

```
if (true)
{
    // some code
    // some more code (text focus is now right here)
}
```

I notice no prompts whatsoever when this behavior occurs, leading me to believe this isn't some "smart" feature that is configurable. Is anyone else experiencing this? If so, what can I do to troubleshoot this?

**EDIT:**

User42's answer below resolved the issue for me, but [here is a video](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F7FCE5CCA52BABF!33806&authkey=!ADwFn_KtR8WnTek&ithint=video%2Cmp4) of the issue taking place for those who are experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Tried with VS2013 and couldn't reproduce it

Comment: Tried with VS2015 and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: Tried with both VS2015 and VS2013 and didn't experience this. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: I could reproduce in VS2015

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it in 2015.... My cursor moves to the next line outside the block as expected.

Comment: I think this doesn't occur this way with Resharper installed, given you really pressed [Tab] two times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reproduced with VS2015.

The reason is that you are still in the middle of filling out the argument for the `if` (see that it is highlighted). Just type the argument and click enter to let VS know you're done. It's a feature, not a bug. :)

Another option  would be to edit the snippet. The snippets are stored in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

I advise you to first make a copy of a snippet before editing.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. I will add that even if I modify the text that the snippet is expecting (for instance, replacing `true` in the `if (true)` portion of the snippet with my own expression), it still is obsessed with my hitting the [Enter] key rather than just letting me click away and be on with my day. Regardless, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @JacobStamm I didn't test it now, but I think you need to move the `$end$` in the snippet to after the `}`.